# ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi3, raspbian-stretch

I am using this tutorial from google

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-iot-core-overview/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2

I was able to perform correctly until I encountered this "`python cloudiot_pubsub_example_server.py`" step.

After executing the above step, I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28'
>   not found (required by
>   /home/pi/Desktop/python-docs-samples/iot/api-client/end_to_end_example/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so

I also attached the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gbbb.png) screenshot for reference

Comment: You need to upgrade your `libc6` package

Comment: thank you rahul for your valuable answer. May i ask you the command for upgrading it? Also i am new to Linux programming. Your help in making me learn how to debug these type of errors can be of great help

Answer (score 5):

As it was mentioned by *@Rahul Agarwal* you should `libc6` package.

It looks like you're using [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/). **To upgrade packages** you should follow the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/apt.md) and simply use commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. **To get the newest version of** `libc6` package you should use [Raspberry Pi OS Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/).

Comment: I have the Raspberry Pi OS Buster on a raspberry PI 4 with all packaged updated but still i'm getting this error : ```ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/pi/Desktop/[...]/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)```